# How can I make \autoref keep the surrounding color?

Tags: hyperref, color, autoref

`\autoref`'s link color is set using the `linkcolor=black` parameter of the `\hypersetup` command of package `hyperref`. This implies that the link color does not regard the color of its surrounding text. How do I make \autoref create links whose text color *does* regard the surroundings? At least in the sense of having the same color as the surrounding text?

Comment: `At least...` as opposed to what? In any case, an example of code would be useful here. Please post a Minimum Working Example people can play with.

Comment: @cfr: As opposed to getting 1/2 * (surrounding color + black) for example.

Comment: But isn't that just what the previous thing says i.e it `regards the surroundings`? When you then say `At least...`, I assume that *ideally* you'd like something additional i.e. a minimally acceptable solution would mean `same colour as the surrounding text`, whereas a truly satisfactory solution would also mean `... something else...`. But what's the something else?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An empty value disables the color, the [example](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/261558/16967) of egreg, simplified without the need for `xcolor` and without explicit color settings for links:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{color}

\usepackage[colorlinks,linkcolor={}]{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\section{Section title}\label{test}

This is an autoref to \autoref{test}

\textcolor{red}{This is an autoref to \autoref{test}}

\end{document}
```

If you do not want to have colors or borders for all kind of links, then option `hidelinks` is, what you are looking for:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{color}

\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\section{Section title}\label{test}

This is an autoref to \autoref{test}

\textcolor{red}{This is an autoref to \autoref{test}}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

With `xcolor` you can refer to the current color with `.`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage[colorlinks,linkcolor=.]{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\section{Section title}\label{test}

This is an autoref to \autoref{test}

\textcolor{red}{This is an autoref to \autoref{test}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hmm... neat. I was sort of expecting something more complicated :-)

Comment: @einpoklum I too. `;-)` But I tried and…